# When console.log(this.selectedValue) I'm getting a null

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to get the value of my select but it isn't being picked up and I'm not sure why I've got v-model on my select tag and as far as I know it should have been picked up.
When I check my console I have a null.

Here is my code.

```js
<template>
    <div class="content-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row mb-2">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <label for="product_select">Products</label>
                                    <select id="product_select" class="form-control" v-model="selectedValue">
                                        <optgroup v-for="product in products" :label="product.text">
                                            <option v-for="list in product.children" :value="list.id">{{ list.text }}</option>
                                        </optgroup>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        props: ['products'],
        data(){
            return {
                selectedValue: null
            }
        },
        computed:{

        },
        watch: {

        },
        methods: {

        }
        mounted() {
          console.log(this.selectedValue);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59680207/auto-select-first-option-in-v-for-vue-js

Answer (score 1):

`mounted` is executed before your 'select' operation.